median() tries to change column to numeric
I am using median() inside of an if-else list comprehension as such:
summary_frame = pd.DataFrame({
# ...
"50%": [df[col].median() if "float" or "int" or "time" in str(df[col].dtype) else df[col].mode() for col in df.columns]
# ...
})

where if the datatype is not numerical, else it should default to mode(), which works when the datatype is not numerical.
however, it tries to convert the series to numerical and throws a TypeError. Is there a way around this?

What is if "float" or "int" or "time" or in str(df[col].dtype) supposed to mean? I think that should get a syntax error because of or in

I think you mean if df[col].dtype in ("float", "int", "time")

For the conditional, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651432/using-in-with-or

damn, and here I was, so sure it wasn't syntax, haha. good catch.

hmm, still throws an error. And yeah double checking it's a TypeError of cannot change array values ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c'...] to numeric. So it's definitely the question described above.

obviously it's doing what it should do, as median is a numerical measure, I'm just curious if there's a lazy solution like if error pass or something

@Barmar no, i dont think so, as "float" could be in dtype but dtype not in "float". rectangle and a square

Oh, you mean if "float" in str(df[col].dtype) or "int" in str(df[col].dtype) or ...

You can simplify that to if any(t in str(df[col].dtype for t in ("float", "int", "time"))

@Barmar yep that's exactly right. nice, will update for performance 

@NickODell is that a link for the LC conditional or a fix for the TypeError?

Change
if "float" or "int" or "time" or in str(df[col].dtype)

to
if any(t in str(df[col].dtype) for t in ("float", "int", "time"))

or in Python is not like English, it doesn't automatically distribute over the comparison operation. You can't write
if x or y or z in something

That's parsed as
if x or y or (z in something)

Full test code:
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 6, 10], 'b': ['a', 'x', 'x', 'foo', 'b', 'x', 'y'] })
>>> summary_frame = pd.DataFrame({'50%': [df[col].median() if any(t in str(df[col].dtype) for t in ("float", "int", "time")) else df[col].mode() for col in df.columns]})
>>> summary_frame
                             50%
0                            3.0
1  0    x
Name: b, dtype: object


original syntax works without error. I think it may be an edge case, as it's an LC inside of an LC... will focus TypeError first, then come back to this optimization later. Thanks for your help @Barmar

You changed the question! Now my answer makes no sense.

If the original syntax worked without error, you must have copied it wrong, because you had an extra or after in.

or was a typo, the exclusion of any() worked without error

again thanks for your help, but you are not answering the question at hand.

Then I don't understand the question. This is the proper way to test if the dtype of the column contains any of those substrings.

ah, it is related. Got it! in this case, yes adding any throws error as shown above.

I had a typo, I was missing the ) at the end of str(df[col].dtype).

same thing man. "t is not defined"

I just tested it and didn't get an error. I updated the answer with the test.

ah, your wizardry has worked. Thank you !!!! Apologies for the ignorance on my part.
